# Trying to connect to user profile page, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm trying to create a navbar link to the profile page of whoever is logged in. I'm using devise for authentication. It keeps throwing various errors. Heres what i have so far.

in the navbar

```js
<li><% yield (:profile)%><%= link_to "My Account", profile_path(user)%></li>
```

in my routes

```js
 get '/:id', to: 'users#show', as: :profile
```

my users_controller

```js
class UsersController < ApplicationController


    def show
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      if current_user !=@user
        redirect_to root_url

  end

end
end
```

with this setup its throwing this error

"undefined local variable or method `user' for #<#:0x007fdb615f4940>"

any tips on fixing?

**EDIT**
now its throwing an error anytime i click on another link in the navbar... heres an example[image]

Comment: what is user here in your navbar ? is it current_user who logged in ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be `current_user` instead of `user`

```
<li><% yield (:profile)%><%= link_to "My Account", profile_path(current_user)%></li>
```

Try to change user profile route

```
get 'user/:id', to: 'users#show', as: :profile
```

Comment: ok, so that worked, but, now anytime I click on anything else in the navbar it throws an error...

Comment: the problem with your route that you defined. it matches any route with this get '/:id', to: 'users#show', as: :profile

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the help!